# How to change my validation to make field optional

Tags: php, sql, input, required

I have some input, but I don't want it to be required, I want it to be optional. However, my validation is making it required.

I need new code with `preg_match`, but without making the field mandatory.

My code is:

```
if(!preg_match("%^(https?://)([a-z0-9-].?)+(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$%i", $temp2)){
    $this->class->obj['post_errors'] = 'no_image';
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If `$temp2` is the user input you are testing, wrap the whole of your `if` statement in `if ($temp2) { ... }`. Thus, the error condition can only be set if there is something to test (in other words, you are changing the validation from required to optional).

Comment: @adamdunson, I think by "required", the OP means "required input" i.e. the control's contents must be non-empty, and must also pass this validation. I think they want to apply the validation _only_ if the control contains something.

Comment: i want to do this input without Required.

Comment: @Omer, I think you mean that you want the field to be optional. That is to say that the validation should only be applied if there is a value in the field. I've edited the post to reflect that, and voted to reopen. (My answer above is all you need, I think).

Comment: @halfer yes!! you right. but what can i do?

Comment: @halfer i dont know what do. my english not so good.

Comment: This is what I meant: http://pastie.org/8339576

Answer (score 0):

I assume `$temp2` comes from a [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.5) value. You may just check if it's empty or not, and if it's not *then* require it to be correct. Otherwise just omit it and don't log an error.

```
if (!empty($temp2)) {
    if(!preg_match("%^(https?://)([a-z0-9-].?)+(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$%i", $temp2)){
        $this->class->obj['post_errors'] = 'no_image';
    }
}
```